# VS Code "tsc is not the same of a cmdlet"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I tried compiling TypeScript with the tsc command, but I got this error:

> tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

Despite having TS installed globally through NPM. How do I get VS Code to transpile TS correctly?

Comment: Does `npx tsc` work? What is the output of `npm list -g --depth 0` for you?

Comment: @ConnorLow I get "This is not the tsc command you are looking for. To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx, or use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages".

I then installed typescript as it instructed. With npm list -g --depth 0, the output was C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- typescript@4.7.4

I then tried using tsc and still got the same error about tsc not being a cmdlet.

Comment: What OS are you? If you install another node cmdlet (e.g. concurrently or rimraf) can you run those successfully?

Comment: @ConnorLow Windows 10. I installed rimraf and the command line told me that it's not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I accidentally removed some Node dependencies while doing some spring cleaning... To solve this, I just reinstalled Node and then used npm to reinstall TS globally.